# Sum of all Sine Waves (Frequencies and Phase)

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

I've been trying to figure out what the waveform of white light, which is the sum of all sine waves with all phases and frequencies, would look like.  I've been trying to graph it on Desmos, but no matter what I do, I come up with something that's non-periodic and seems to approach zero as x goes to plus or minus infinity (so I'm pretty sure it's wrong).

What I've done so far is first find the sum of all sine waves with frequencies between $f_1$ and $f_2$ at some arbitrary phase $p_1$, so

$$
\int_{f_1}^{f^2} \sin(tx + p_1) dt = \frac{cos(f_1x+p_1)}{x} - \frac{cos(f_2x+p_1)}{x}
$$

which looks like this for $f_1=1$and $f_2=30$

[image: Sum of sine waves with varying frequency]

Next, I take the integral of that for varying phases.

$$
\int_{p_1}^{p_2} ( \frac{cos(f_1x+t)}{x} - \frac{cos(f_2x+t)}{x} ) dt
$$

which I was too lazy to compute by hand and just let Desmos take care of it:

[image: The sum of all sine waves with varying frequencies and phases?]

It looks interesting, but I'm pretty sure that's not what white looks like.  So I'm wondering, how do you graph the sum of all sine functions with various frequencies and various phases?

Note, I don't think white noise is what I'm looking for.  White noise is just random frequencies, but as far as I'm aware, white light is the sum of all frequencies (of course, I could be wrong in which case I'd be curious as to whether my graph of all sine waves is correct)

Comment: I assume that the x axis is time in your figures. What would white look like in the time domain? Also, why do you assume that all frequencies and phases have the same weight?

Comment: Also, why do you integrate in time, but the integral limits are in frequencies?

Comment: @Andrei I think the x axis would just be another spacial axis.  For example, a pure color would be an ordinary sine wave with both axes being spacial.  Using "t" for the integrals was arbitary.  I suppose "f" and "p" would have made more sense.  As for why they should all have the same weight, I know that red, green, and blue would all have to have the same weight at least in order for it to appear white, but I suppose if my math is correct, then my understanding of white must not be.